# Data Scrambling function

Tags: javascript, c#

```
public static string ScrambleData(string data)
{
    //string BaseAddress = "http://localhost/";
    string CompleteRequestURL = "http://abcd:8090/Scrambler?value=" + data;

    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(CompleteRequestURL);
    //webrequest.Method = "GET";

    webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    string result;

    using (WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ScrambleData(result);
}
```

Here I have created `ScrambleData()` function for scrambling the data. I need to call this function in `Button1_Click` event. Not able to call this function correctly. Can any one help me please..???

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Javascript is used for to display the user selected data.

Comment: What will be the expected value for `Data`

Comment: The scrambling value has to display.

Comment: Your C# code has a glaring bug because you don't URL-encode the `data`. Also, the content type of your request is most definitely not `application/json`. Finally, is this question basically *"How can I make a web request from Javascript"*? Because if that's the case, then I encourage you to read one of the ten thousands of blog posts, StackOverflow answers and tutorials that have been written over the years that show how to make HTTP requests from JS. Seriously, this is such a basic operation that you cannot NOT find any existing posts that explain it.